# How do I access the same flutter projects from different computers (not at the same time) (Android studio, flutter)

Tags: flutter

How can I access my flutter projects from different computers?
I use Android studio to build my flutter projects and currently I am working on an app, and I would like to access this project while at home and at my workplace. Is there a way to save the project in cloud or elsewhere to be able to access it from any device. I have tried to copy and paste the project, it does seem to work, but there is so much issues that I have to take care of before I can start working on the app again.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: use a version controller like github.com

Answer (score 1):

There are many version control systems available for this purpose.
Here are a few you can use:

-GitHub

-GitLab

-BitBucket

Comment: I have managed to set up git. However I had one question.

Comment: I have managed to set up git. However, I have a question. So, when I access a project from computer A, and I make some changes and in order for me to see those changes from computer B, I will have to push the changes from computer A ? How do I access the changed sourcecode from computer B? Do i create a new project or I cannot see git when i try to open an existing project.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks